# I have 2 pc servers in My network that I can't find a way to get rid of

Tags: macos, network

I have 2 pc servers that show in My network that I can't find a way to get rid of. They are.. home_network_ga and zoey ..Zoey is the name of My computer. If I delete the SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server.plist they disappear for a few minutes after I restart then returns. I have a Macbook Pro A1260 with El Capitan. Anyone got any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Since macOS will present all shared resources, do you want to work on the network side to remove them from the network or perhaps just hide the all detected resources and leave them available for connection since they do exist on your local network?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'd like to remove them from the network.

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable Bonjour.  Disabling Bonjour client services is not supported through the OS GUI.

See http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050707222434355

Searching for "osx disable Bonjour client services" might turn up some helpful answers.